# Parse a PHP array in a JS file with a JS variable inside the PHP parsed array -YII2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, yii2

How should I do this?

```
 $ids = ArrayHelper::map(Tours::find()->select(['pk', 'programa'])->asArray()->all(), 'pk', 'programa');


$this->registerJs('
$("#child1_child2").change(function() {
    var val = $("#child1_child2 option:selected").val();
    valInt = parseInt(val);
    $("#form").attr("action", "programas/" + "'.$ids[.'"valInt"'.].'");
});
', \yii\web\View::POS_END);
```

I dont know how to parse this part:

```
$("#form").attr("action", "programas/" + "'.$ids[.'"valInt"'.].'");
```

$ids it's a php array

valInt is a js varibale

I thought this was correct but I'm getting parse error

```
syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']'
```

if I write `"'.$ids[40].'"`  it works great and with no errors.

Thi is in the view of site/index.php, working with Yii2.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can't pass JS you're outputting back to the server and expect a response without using AJAX. Alternatively, you can put a json encoded version of $ids as a var in the JS and then index the JS version of $ids...

Comment: You might emit the **$ids** so that it was a javascript array on the client and then you could index it with **valInt**

Comment: but "'.$ids[40].'" its working fine or is not related?

Comment: It's working because $ids[40] is set as a php array. The problem is that you're trying to get the statically generated JS to be dynamic before it's sent to the browser. That won't fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$ids = ArrayHelper::map(Tours::find()->select(['pk', 'programa'])->asArray()->all(), 'pk', 'programa');


$this->registerJs('
$("#child1_child2").change(function() {
    var val = $("#child1_child2 option:selected").val();
    valInt = parseInt(val);
    var $ids = '. json_encode($ids) .';
    $("#form").attr("action", "programas/" + $ids[valInt]);
});
', \yii\web\View::POS_END);
```